# What application uses a red cone icon with a notch in it?

Tags: icon

I saw the following icons in a screen shot of a mac. I know the F-icon is Autodesk Fusion, but what is the icon next to it, the red cone with a notch?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That appears to be the icon for [Autodesk AutoCAD](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad/features/documentation-files/autodesk-desktop-app) (see the red icon in the screenshot).

[Here](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/simply-styled-icons-by-dakirby309/Autodesk-Autocad-icon.html) is another view.

Comment: I should have guessed since Fusion is right next to it, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Open it and look at the name on the menu bar in the top left?

Comment: This is a screenshot from a video on YouTube. This application is not on my computer.

Comment: Ah, now we know.